# CSS minify default feature of Magento is not working

Tags: javascript, css, magento, minify

I don't know why.

It is treating CSS files fine; combining & minifying. But that's not the case with JS's minification.
I have tried a # of Magento extensions to achieve the result like Webo, JS/CSS optimisation & minification by Diglin, Fooman Speedster, etc. But none of them proved to be useful, instead produced errors.

Have you ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to clean all your css code.

- Errors in css;
- Load all your css files with layouts;
- Don't load same css more than once;

I experience this many times and always do the same for solve this problem.
When everything goes fine in css, minify should works nice.

It's not so easy, but try to be ["W3C friendly"](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).